# How do i make my code editor look like the one on Github Copilot's website?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I know this isn't strictly code related, but i know that vscode is used in the [github copilot website](https://copilot.github.com/). However, how do i get my ide and copilot suggestions to look like that?

Comment: choose a nice theme and font

Comment: which one for the one on the website tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hard to tell the exact theme they used there, it might not even exist.

Anyway, the font is this one: [Cascadia Code Web](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code), it comes with installation instructions and [here it is described how to install it in vs code](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/wiki/Installing-Cascadia-Code)

For the theme colors, I am not quite sure as I said, but it does look similar to the github dark color theme, just install the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.github-vscode-theme) and press `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T` and select `Github dark` from the dropdown

It's not the exact look, but hope it helps